# Unable to load ted_hrlr_translate/pt_to_en dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow-datasets, transformer-model

I was running transformer[[link]](https://colab.research.google.com/github/dlmacedo/starter-academic/blob/master/content/courses/deeplearning/notebooks/tensorflow/transformer.ipynb#scrollTo=8q9t4FmN96eN) code in my jupyter notebook by looking at the google collab code. The tfds.load was able to load ted_hrlr_translate/pt_to_en dataset in collab but was unable in jupyter notebook. The error that hit the screen was :

> Failed to construct dataset ted_hrlr_translate: Message type
> "tensorflow_datasets.DatasetInfo" has no field named "releaseNotes".
> Available Fields(except extensions): ['name', 'description',
> 'version', 'configName', 'configDescription', 'citation',
> 'sizeInBytes', 'downloadSize', 'location', 'downloadChecksums',
> 'schema', 'splits', 'supervisedKeys', 'redistributionInfo',
> 'moduleName', 'disableShuffling', 'fileFormat']

Is this a bug or I am too dumb to understand the error?
Do I need to download the dataset? If so then i was able to load mnist data in jupyter notebook without downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

This did not show any error to me when I tried to import this dataset using same line of code in `jupyter` notebook with `TensorFlow 2.7`. However please let us know which `TensorFlow version` are you using to replicate the issue into the same.

Meanwhile, you can try with installing below packages before of importing datasets in `jupyter` notebook.

```
#For the stable version, released every few months.
!pip install tensorflow-datasets  

#Released every day, contains the last versions of the datasets.
!pip install tfds-nightly
```